# Showing that $D^{-1}- A'( A D A')^{-1} A$ is positive semi-definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

Suppose $\mathbf A$ is an $n \times r$ matrix and $\mathbf D$ a diagonal $r \times r$ matrix with all elements in the diagonal strictly positive. Also $\mathbf A\mathbf D\mathbf A'$ is invertible. I need to show that

$$ \mathbf D^{-1}-\mathbf A'(\mathbf A\mathbf D\mathbf A')^{-1}\mathbf A $$

is positive semi-definite. I am not sure where to start from though. Any hints would be very welcome.

Comment: I would start with the definition and try to simplify $u^T M u$ where $M$ is your complicated expression above.

Comment: @hardmath Thanks. I tried this, but it didn't really go anywhere...

Comment: That in turn is an early indication that you are trying to prove something that isn't true, and that attention should shift to trying examples.  I note that when $A$ itself is square and invertible, the expression simplifies to zero, which is a "positive semi-definite" matrix technically.

Comment: We need $n \le r$ and $A$ of full rank in order for $ADA'$ to be invertible.

Comment: @hardmath I've tried many examples and haven't found a counter-example yet.

Comment: Notice that in its current form the Question does not assume $D$ is positive definite.

Comment: @hardmath You are right about that. I forgot to add that assumption, I'll do it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per hardmath's suggestion: Let $y = D^{-1/2}x$, and let $B = AD^{1/2}$.  We can rewrite 
$$
D^{-1} - A'(ADA')^{-1}A = \\
D^{-1/2}(I - D^{1/2}A'(AD^{1/2}D^{1/2}A')^{-1}AD^{1/2})D^{-1/2} =\\
D^{-1/2}(I - B'(BB')^{-1}B)D^{-1/2}
$$
To show that $I - B'(BB')^{-1}B$ is positive definite, it suffices to note that $B'(BB')^{-1}B$ defines the *orthogonal projection* onto the row-space of $B$.  In particular, $B'(BB')^{-1}B y$ produces $B'x$, where $x$ solves the "least squares" equation $BB'x = By$.  So, $I - B'(BB')^{-1}B$ defines the projection onto the orthogonal complement of the row-space.

---

For a more computational ending: $M = B'(BB')^{-1}B$ is symmetric with $M^2 = M$.  So, its eigenvalues are in $\{0,1\}$.  So, the eigenvalues of $I - M$ are also in $\{0,1\}$.  So, $I - M$ is symmetric with non-negative eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1):

**Thoughts**

- We know that $A$ is of full (row) rank since $ADA'$ is invertible.  So, there exists a $B$ with $AB = I_{r \times r}$.
- This manipulation of the inequality

$$ x'\mathbf D^{-1}x-x'\mathbf A'(\mathbf A\mathbf D\mathbf A')^{-1}\mathbf Ax \geq 0 \iff \\
x'\mathbf D^{-1}x\geq x'\mathbf A'(\mathbf A\mathbf D\mathbf A')^{-1}\mathbf Ax  \iff \\
x'\mathbf D^{-1}x\geq (\mathbf A x)'(\mathbf A\mathbf D\mathbf A')^{-1}(\mathbf Ax) \iff\\ 
\frac{(\mathbf A x)'(\mathbf A\mathbf D\mathbf A')^{-1}(\mathbf Ax)}{x'\mathbf D^{-1}x} \leq 1 \\
$$

Comment: With the added assumption that $D$ is positive definite, we can "absorb" the square root factors of $D$ into $A,A'$ and thereby reduce consideration to the cases $D=I$.

Comment: @hardmath I can't believe I didn't think of that!  That completely solves it.